# 2D-Fourier transform of $(r,\theta) \mapsto (1 + \mathrm{i} \cos ( \theta ))^{-1}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in polar coordinates by
$$ f(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{i} \cos ( \theta )}.$$
The function $f$ is in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R^2})$ so that its Fourier transform is well-defined.

**Question:** Is there a nice closed-form expression for the Fourier transform of $f$?

Comment: Yes: do the maths.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit?..